# why jquery datepicker doesn't work on textarea but only on input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please help me, i'm clueless. when I try to open the date picker of the jquery UI and attach it to input tag it works perfectly, but when i try to attach it to textarea nothing is happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {    $("#${data_picker}").datepicker();  });
</script>

---- This will work ----
<input id="data_picker" />

---- This doesn't work ----
<textarea id="data_picker"></textarea>
```

why???

p.s 
of course they're not in the same page together, it's only the input or only the textarea in the page.

Comment: Why use a textarea for a date value in the first place?

Comment: This is the deafult display method in our system.

Answer (score 5):

Short version: datepicker just isn't supported with a `<textarea>` element, specifically it's supported with [`<span>` and `<div>` elements](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L154) for [inline mode](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline) and [only `<input>` elements](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L161) otherwise.  Here's the relevant code doing these checks:

```
var nodeName = target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
var inline = (nodeName == 'div' || nodeName == 'span');
if (!target.id) {
  this.uuid += 1;
  target.id = 'dp' + this.uuid;
}
var inst = this._newInst($(target), inline);
inst.settings = $.extend({}, settings || {}, inlineSettings || {});
if (nodeName == 'input') {
  this._connectDatepicker(target, inst);
} else if (inline) {
  this._inlineDatepicker(target, inst);
}
```

Comment: I manage to change the datepicker code to make it work with textarea, how can i upload it to here?

Comment: @Rotem - I'm not following...this isn't really a code sharing site - and there are reasons (events and a few options that don't work property) that the code specifically excludes `<textarea>` currently, did you resolve all those?  For example how would you handle browsers with resizable `<textarea>` elements? (the default in chrome)

Comment: well, actually I only need to support IE and FF. But after couple of hour of trying to implement it on my web application I decided to not use it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a way to make datepicker work for textareas in my app.

I added a input text field  in my html code, with `style="display:none"` so that this field will be hidden, but the calendar button is displayed as an image. the user clicks on the image and when he selects a date, I have the 'onSelect' function implemented below that will add the value to a text area. I think the original implementation uses .append() to add the value to an input text.. this is why it doesn't work for textareas... my solution is using val() and it worked as expected for me, so I'm sharing it with you

```
jQuery(inputEl).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../image/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            var textStr = jQuery(txtAreaEl).val();
            textStr = selectedDate;
            jQuery(txtAreaEl).val(textStr);
        } 
    });
```