# bootstrap datepicker not working in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to implement bootstrap date and time picker in my web app using this http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ .I have a textArea which accepts only 160 charcters. I am using this way

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
     <!-- <input type="password"></input>-->
<textarea name="hi" ></textarea>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Even if you select some date and time then its not reflected in the textarea though it works if the input type is text.Please tell me what to modify.
this is the js

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'eng'
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something i just made.Both autocomplete and datepicker

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
 #datepicker {
 display: inline-block;
width: 35px;
height: 34px;
position: relative;
left: -5px;
top: -189px;

  background:url("date.png") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
}
 </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
   $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ altField: '#dtext',onSelect: function() { $("#datepicker").val(""); $("#dtext").change(); }

  });
  $('#dtext').change(function(){ 


     $(".darea").val($( ".darea" ).val()+$( "#dtext" ).val());
  });
});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">


   <textarea rows="9" cols="50" class="darea" id="tags"></textarea>
<input  id="datepicker"></input>
<input type="text" id="dtext" style="display:none"/>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the link it is said that it supports in div,In my case its div too

Comment: So you say I need to make textarea to input type =text

Comment: You can do that but as you said that user have to enter large text.so just out of curiosity , cant you enlarge the text box and make it look like a textarea

Comment: is it possble to increase the height and width

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39896/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-bharath-rallapalli)

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice that you have edited your answer.Just now i check ed after you made a comment

Comment: did you check the mail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it supports text areas. You need a text input like this:

```
<input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: I have textarea because user have to enter large text some 160 characters.If i make it to input type =text then it will not look good

Comment: Y dont you enlarge your input box , so that will be a win win for all.

Comment: @javaBeginner aren't your users simply inputting a date?

Comment: @BharathRallapalli can i increase the width and height of input type=text

Comment: @BharathRallapalli let us contniue the discussion in chat

Comment: @BharathRallapalli please check the mail

Answer (score 0):

datepicker just isn't supported with a  element, specifically it's supported span/div/input

go on this link : [why jquery datepicker doesn't work on textarea but only on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117727/why-jquery-datepicker-doesnt-work-on-textarea-but-only-on-input)